# GAE App.yaml - separate directories for src and build static files

Tags: google-app-engine, backbone.js, r.js

Is it possible to optionally override a static files directory in the Google App Engine [app.yaml](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig#Static_File_Pattern_Handlers) file if another directory exists? I have a source directory (unminified) and a build directory (minified and concatenated). I want Google App Engine to automatically use the build directory instead of the src directory, if it exists. That way I can dev using the src directory, then create a build and deploy it. Then, if I delete the build directory, GAE goes back to serving my static files from the src directory.

The reason I need to do this is because I am building an application with Backbone.js & Require.js as modules. I need to be able to [optimize](http://requirejs.org/docs/optimization.html#wholeproject) my code and deploy without changing my app.yaml file every time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty happy with my current system where my framework uses different paths in the templates to the source javascript files.  Then at startup, through a combination of checking os.environ and get_application_id() I automatically detect whether I'm running locally on dev_appserver, or under my test appid or production appid on GAE.

And on to the next step, you most likely want to cache your minified JS aggressively, in which case you'd be unable to force clients to update a new version.  The typical workaround is to append a hash or date string to the minified js filename whenever it's updated.  This is something you'll also need to do in your framework/templating layer instead of app.yaml.

Comment: ok, makes sense, so does that mean that you deploy both the src and build folders up to Google App Engine? And does that mean that you have to have separate endpoints in app.yaml for them? To get around the caching, I can probably use the file modified timestamp.

Comment: I've got 2 GAE apps running the same, code, one for testing, and one is production.  On the test app.yaml I upload both src/build folders, since I sometimes do want to use js from the src folder since it's easier to debug (I just flip a setting to my framework uses js from the src folder).  On the production app.yaml, I left out the src folder since it's never required.  I have a deploy script that copies my test/production yaml to the actual "app.yaml" file before deploy.

Comment: How do you handle static file paths refered to in your static files? For instance, here's a font path in my CSS. `background: url("../imgs/bg-body.jpg")` I have to expose `/imgs` as either the src or build directory in my app.yaml. If I expose the src directory as `/imgs` the files will be there, but they will not have gone through an optimization step that I've built them with. The same goes for CSS, fonts and HTML templates.

Comment: I update my paths in my CSS build process.  In my equivalent, /imgs will always contain the source, and /bin/imgs will contain the optimized ones.  The minified css will point to /bin/imgs.

Answer (score 1):

I would do this at the template layer - when you go to render the template that includes links to your assets, check to see if the minified version exists. If it does, link to that - otherwise, link to the unminified version.

This also helps if you accidentally deploy without creating a build - you'll just be serving unoptimized assets.

Comment: do you deploy both the src and build folders up to Google App Engine? And does that mean that you have to have separate endpoints in app.yaml for them?

Comment: Yes. Your template rendering code would be responsible for figuring out which endpoint to link to, depending on whether the optimized folder existed.

Comment: How do you handle static file paths files refered to in your static files? For instance, here's an image path in my CSS. 
`background: url("../imgs/bg-body.jpg")`
I have to expose `/imgs` as either the src or build directory in my app.yaml. If I expose the src directory as `/imgs` the files will be there, but they will not have gone through an optimization step that I've built them with. The same goes for CSS, fonts and HTML templates.

Comment: Shouldn't your optimizer be converting those paths to the optimized paths when it optimizes your CSS?